# Can you change the tab referenced on an excel file imbedded into a powerpoint presentation?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I am having difficulty referencing specific tabs of an imbedded excel file to separate slides in a powerpoint.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to display a particular tab, drag the object into the slide, right click the worksheet and select Worksheet Object, Edit.
From there you can slect a different tab, etc. When finished click out of the worksheet to freeze the view.